# mfc accelerators Ctrl + doesn't work

Tags: c++, mfc, acceleratorkey

I have mfc application where I defined keyboard ACCELERATORS
It works fine when I use alphanumeric characters, but I want to define an accelerators that zoomin/zoomout while pressing on the keys <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd>
so I defined it as the following and it works fine

```
 ID1 ACCELERATORS DISCARDABLE
 {
   "+",  ID_ZOOMIN ,  ,ASCII, NOINVERT      
   "-",   ID_ZOOMIN ,ASCII, NOINVERT        
 }
```

Now I added a text box that can accept "+/-" as charcters but pressing on them now function as zoomin/zoomout and the characters "+/-" are not typed
so I changed my implementation to have the "zoomin/zoomout" functionality only works while the control button is pressed

```
 ID1 ACCELERATORS DISCARDABLE
 {
   "+",  ID_ZOOMIN ,  ,ASCII, CONTROL, NOINVERT      
   "-",   ID_ZOOMIN ,ASCII, CONTROL, NOINVERT        
 }
```

but still pressing <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>" function as "zoomin/zoomout" and the <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> characters are not typed 
Note: changing ASCII to VIRTKEY doesn't solve the problem

Any ideas??

Comment: Use Visual Studio's automated approach, don't type.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but I need more elaboration ??  I'm using Linux OS

Comment: you can use MFC on Linux using a third party "mainsoft"

Comment: it should works the same way as Windows , All I need is to know what is wrong with my code and how to fix it , why "+/-" don't work as other keys

Comment: I just can say, it's not normal. Adding CONTROL usually doesn't do any difference, if bare '+', '-' key accelerators are really worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested with my Windows laptop. It seems ASCII accelerators don't support the `CONTROL` modifier.

Use `VIRTKEY` instead.

```
 ID1 ACCELERATORS DISCARDABLE
 {
   107,  ID_ZOOMIN,  VIRTKEY, CONTROL, NOINVERT      
   109,  ID_ZOOMOUT,  VIRTKEY, CONTROL, NOINVERT        
 }
```

Or specify `VK_ADD` for <kbd>+</kbd>, `VK_SUBTRACT` for <kbd>-</kbd>.

[Windows Virtual-Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I have tried your proposal but now pressing on "+/-" type the characters "+/-" to the text box but the zooming in/out is not working clicking on "Ctrl + or Ctrl -" also type the characters

Comment: @mizohazem Then, maybe VK_OEM_PLUS and VK_OEM_MINUS?